# How to test for statistical significance between three differently sized groups with categorical outcomes that include zero counts?

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data

I have data consisting of three type of tumors (see column names, counts per tumor at the bottom of each column). A tumor can be tested and be given a score (negative, weak, moderate, strong). The cells indicate the respective counts. I want to test whether the different tumors get significantly different scores on this test. I don't know which test to use, how to cope with this big difference in the amount of data and how to cope with the zero counts that appear in three cells.

[image: The data in question]

Comment: The alternative of interest matters. Are you more interested in a shift up / down the categories (a tendency to be  higher/lower on this score, presumably representing worse/better indication) or would *any* kind of difference matter - e.g. imagine a comparison of the 1st and second columns; would you care to detect a tendency for column 2 to have fewer *weak* values  but simultaneously more *moderate* and *negative* values (a 'polarization'  of categories, rather than a shift up or down)

Comment: Good point, I should have mentioned that. I am mainly interested in the first, but now that you mention the other point, I am also interested in that. I suspected that the first column 'undifferentiated', would have more 'negative' values.

Comment: If you're interested in every possible kind of difference in distribution, the ordering of the ordered variable doesn't matter (indeed it contributes no information); you can treat the ordered variable as unordered (and do an ordinary test of independence). Note also that by broadening the set of alternatives you want to be able to capture (leading to the ordering being irrelevant), you will lose power against the specific ordered alternatives you had in mind. ...

Comment: ... If you had had enough values in the uppermost (`strong`) category to support it, one *sort of* intermediate possibility is to decompose the chi-squared into orthogonal linear, quadratic and cubic components; the first of which would be sensitive to the "higher/lower" sort of difference. I think this sort of decomposition is straightforward  for an explicitly ordered factor in R (as I recall, it works in `lm`; I presume it would also work in a binomial glm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an ordinal outcome (ordered categories from negative to strong) with an arguably unordered categorical predictor (tumor type).

If there were sufficient counts in all cells, you could just use some standard frequentist maximum-likelihood approach to ordinal data (e.g. ordinal logistic regression). The zero and near-zero counts might cause some problems there, although it might work.

An alternative is a Bayesian version of this, where you can regularize the coefficients by introducing weakly informative proper prior distribution (or if you want to and have prior information, you could also use informative priors). Bayesian models with weakly informative proper prior distributions tend to have good small sample performance. One good option for having modeling flexibility there is the `brms` R package, for which there is a [whole in-depth tutorial](https://osf.io/gyfj7/download) (that also got [published in a journal](https://doi.org/10.1177/2515245918823199)) on how to fit such models with explanations of what each option assumes and how to be more flexible with [distributional regression](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_distreg.html) (e.g. do you want to estimate an overall "tendency to be in a higher category"-effect, or do you want to estimate a separate coefficient for being in a category vs. a the next higher category etc.).